# React - Latest versions or latest dependencies versions does not like an apostrophe in the file path

Tags: reactjs

My name has an apostrophe in it and the company I currently work at created my Windows account with the apostrophe. This results in a file path using my name with an apostrophe.

When doing an npm start with React, I get the following error:
I'm getting the following error:

./src/index.js 1:49
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:49)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js

I created a separate account without an apostrophe and it works without error.
Note: I do NOT add the path anywhere in the code. The path is picked up automatically.

I know that it worked with an older version of React and its accompanying older version dependencies but to figure out what line of code or which dependency was added or taken out is a monumental task.

**This is the package.json on the old version where it worked:**

```json
{
  "name": "reactcertification",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": { "extends": "react-app" },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**This is the package.json in the new version where it does not work:**

```json
{
  "name": "monstersrolodex",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": { "extends": ["react-app", "react-app/jest"] },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm just interested in what may have changed. I don't have an issue in using an account without the dreaded apostrophe but it would be nice to know why it doesn't work with the newer versions.

No problem if no one can answer this question. All is good. Be happy. :D

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be [a known issue](https://github.com/npm/cmd-shim/issues/45) in npm utilities that they have not yet fixed.

Can you just run your code from a different folder?